# SQLAlchemy - filter specific column after using 'joinedload' options in query

Tags: join, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I have 3 tables and the corresponding models:

```
# Table Objects: id, name, description

class Objects(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'objects'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(Text())
    description = Column(Text())
    person_related = relationship('Person', secondary=ObjectsPerson.__tablename__, back_populates='objects_related')

# Table Person: id, name, age, company, phone, email

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(Text())
    age = Column(Integer())
    company = Column(Text())
    phone = Column(Text())
    email = Column(Text())
    object_related = relationship('Objects', secondary=ObjectsPerson.__tablename__, back_populates='person_related')

# Table Objects-Person: id, objectid, personid

class ObjectsPerson(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'objects_person'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True, index=True)
    object_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey("objects.id"), nullable=False)
    person_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey("person.id"), nullable=False)
```

The goal is to get all person name managing each object. Only extract the column 'name', not all columns in table 'Person'. Here is the query I did:

```
session.query(Objects).options(joinedload(Objects.person_related)).all()
```

However, after using 'joinedload', the output shows all the columns in table 'Person' instead of showing only one column 'name'. I tried 'with_entities', and other JOIN clauses as well but it throws error.

Any solutions for this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the fields loaded by any query with [`load_only`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.load_only).

```py
results = (
    session
    .query(Objects)
    .options(joinedload(Objects.person_related).load_only(Person.name))
    .all()
)
```

Also looks like there is a typo in `Person.object_related`, I recommend either you use plural for all your classes and tables (Person - person, Object - object), or singular for the class and plural for the table (Person - persons, Object - objects), the `Objects` class makes little sense as it represents a single object.